# Deploying nodejs website on host server

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, web-hosting, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have developed a nodejs based website. It is working perfectly on my local PC, Heroku & Now server as well. Recently I purchased a hosting server from FastComet. Then simply uploaded my nodejs files VIA FileZilla to public_html folder. Then I login into the server VIA putty and installed the dependencies using "npm install". The server is cloudlinux OS based. Then I tried to run my nodejs server using "npm start", but I cannot see my website running in my website, just showing my files in the server. Can you please tell me how can I configure my nodejs in this server ? Should I change the port(3000) to my hosting server port(17177) ?
I am new to hosting configuration. Any guidance would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I hope by now you have solved this out, the team of FastComet did a good job helping me on setting up my node app, you just need to add these lines to the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P] #Change 8000 for your custom port
```

After doing that I was able to running node.js, but after that an unexpected bug appeared. I wasn't able to access '/' in an express app, that was because Apache was looking for `index.html.var` as the DirectoryIndex if you are having this bug, you just need to add

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

to the `.htaccess`and in my case it did work

Comment: Hi Martiuh,Could you please describe what I should provide for my app or I need to provide exactly same as:  RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P] #Change 8000 for your custom port

Comment: Hi Yash, here's my whole [.htaccess](https://gist.github.com/martiuh/6e36ab2a38ac2ed81a16ca6904f2ce1d)

Comment: WOOOWWW Legendary man I am now running my express app on shared hosting :D